# Changing versions in Python without uninstalling it

Tags: python, cmd, version, updates, downgrade

I want to go back to python 3.6 and I have python 3.9 because some of the libraries such as numba is not compatible with it on windows 10. I do not use conda or anything. Is there anyway I could downgrade my python version without uninstalling and reinstalling everything?

```
C:\Users\maste>python -V
Python 3.9.1
```

Comment: You can have 3.6 alongside 3.9 without any issues. Just install it and then create a venv to use 3.6.

Comment: I think this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f/) would help you with what you're trying.